# How to keep a button visible when clicking on other buttons?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a tic tac toe game, and I have created 2 buttons "Quit" and "Replay". When I click on any other buttons, those 2 buttons disappear. I'd be happy if you tell what I can do to have them visible when I click on any other buttons.

As you can see in both screenshots, before I click on any buttons, both are visible, but when I click on any button, both disappear, and I have to hover my mouse over them for them appear again.

[image: Click here for the image]

[image]

```
Below is all of code



public static void main(String[] args) {
    TickTacToe tik = new TickTacToe();
}
 
    Random random = new Random();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel title_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel button_panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel textfield = new JLabel();
    JButton[] buttons_array = new JButton[9];
    int i =0;
    JPanel panel;
     
    JButton Replaybutton,Quitbutton;
    boolean player1_turn;

 
    TickTacToe(){
        JButton Replay,Quit;
        Replay = new JButton();
         
        Replay.setText("Replay?");
        Replay.setForeground(Color.cyan);
        Replay.setFont(new Font("Courgette",Font.BOLD,17));
        Replay.setBackground(new Color(25,60,80));
        Replay.setBounds(70,10, 100,45);
         
        Quit = new JButton();
         
        Quit.setText("Quit!");
        Quit.setForeground(Color.black);
        Quit.setFont(new Font("Courgette",Font.BOLD,19));
        Quit.setBackground(new Color(145,80,120));
        Quit.setBounds(620, 10, 100, 45);
     
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //Below line is for centring our frame in the middle.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         
         
     
        textfield.setBackground(Color.black);
        textfield.setForeground(new Color(80,170,20));
        textfield.setFont(new Font("Courgette",Font.PLAIN,50));
        //The below method is for centering our text in the center.
        textfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textfield.setText("Tik-Tac-Toe");
        textfield.setOpaque(true);
         
         
         
        title_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        title_panel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 100);
         
        button_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        button_panel.setBackground(new Color(150,150,150));
         
         
     
        for(int i = 0; i <9;i++) {
            buttons_array[i] = new JButton();
            button_panel.add(buttons_array[i]);
            buttons_array[i].setFont(new Font("InkFree",Font.BOLD,120));
            buttons_array[i].setFocusable(false);
            buttons_array[i].addActionListener(this);
             
         
        }
         
     
         
     
        frame.add(Replay);
        frame.add(Quit);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        title_panel.add(textfield);
        frame.add(title_panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button_panel);
         
        firstTurn();
    }
     
     
     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(e.getSource()==buttons_array[i]) {
                 
                if(player1_turn) {
                    if(buttons_array[i].getText()=="") {
                        buttons_array[i].setForeground(Color.red);
                        buttons_array[i].setText("X");
                        player1_turn =false;
                        textfield.setText("O Turn");
                        check();
                         
                    }
                }
                 
                else {
                    if(buttons_array[i].getText()=="") {
                        buttons_array[i].setForeground(Color.blue);
                        buttons_array[i].setText("O");
                        player1_turn =true;
                        textfield.setText("X Turn");
                        check();
                         
                    }
                }
            }
             
        }
         
    }
     
    public void firstTurn() {
         
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
        if(random.nextInt(2)==0) {
            player1_turn = true;
            textfield.setText("X Turn");
             
        }else if(random.nextInt(2) == 1) {
             
            player1_turn = false;
            textfield.setText("O Turn");
             
        }
    }
     
    public void check() {
         
        // Checking for x win Conditiotns.
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[1].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[2].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(0,1,2);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[3].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[5].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(3,4,5);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[6].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[7].getText() == "X" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() == "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(6,7,8);
        }
     
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[3].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[6].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(0,3,6);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[1].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[7].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(1,4,7);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[2].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[5].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(2,5,8);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() == "X" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(0,4,8);
        }
         
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[2].getText() == "X") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "X" &&
                buttons_array[6].getText() ==  "X"
                 
                ) {
             
            xWins(2,4,6);
        }
         
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[1].getText() ==  "O"  &&
                buttons_array[2].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
             
            oWins(0,1,2);
             
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[3].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[5].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(3,4,5);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[6].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[7].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(6,7,8);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[3].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[6].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(0,3,6);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[1].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[7].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(1,4,7);
        }
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[2].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[5].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(2,5,8);
        }
         
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[0].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[8].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(0,4,8);
        }
         
         
        if(
                (buttons_array[2].getText() == "O") &&
                buttons_array[4].getText() ==  "O" &&
                buttons_array[6].getText() ==  "O"
                 
                ) {
             
            oWins(2,4,6);
         
             
        }
         
    }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             
           
     
         
     
     
    public void xWins(int a, int b, int c) {
         
        buttons_array[a].setBackground(new Color(50,15,80));
        buttons_array[b].setBackground(new Color(150,15,80));
        buttons_array[c].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
         
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            buttons_array[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: Would have been also a good idea to add the tag: `swing` to your question. I'm experienced in Java and JavaFX and didn't understand the question before realizing you were talking about Swing. I would recommend always mentioning which programming language and which framework/library/etc you use so others can quickly help you. Also, add as many relevant tags as necessary (there are people who watch specific tags - you could have been helped faster this way).

Comment: Another piece of advice would be to start using JavaFX since JavaFX is the successor of Swing and AWT. JavaFX is not so difficult to learn, it's very easy. See https://openjfx.io (there are easy install guides on the website - I would recommend JetBrains IntelliJ idea community to start with which has maven built into it and from there it's easy to use OpenJFX/JavaFX).

Comment: 1) `Don't use a null layout!` Don't use setBounds(). 2) Post a proper [mre] with every question demonstrating the problem. We have no idea how those lines of code are used in the context of your code. We don't even see where you add the buttons to the panel. 3) Variable names should NOT start with upper case characters. Learn and follow Java naming conventions when posting code for other to read.

Comment: (1-) 3) this is not an [mre]. Game logic is not relevant to the stated question. 2) Even if the game logic was relevant it is still not an MRE because we can not copy/paste/compile/test the posted code. There is no class. The "owins" logic is not included. 3) The answer to your question is given in comments 1/2 above which you choose to ignore because someone posted complete code. However that answer doesn't tell you what is wrong with your code, so you don't learn anything about debugging your class. I suggest you first understand the comments and fix your code, then use the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section. Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I created the following GUI.

[image: Example]

I used Swing layout managers to create a button `JPanel` and a tic-tac-toe grid `JPanel`.  You can press any button you want, and all the buttons remain visible on the `JFrame`.

I left all the coloring and fonts for you to add.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern. This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one small part of the application at a time.

For a Swing GUI, the MVC pattern is defined as:

1. The view reads information from the model.
2. The view does not update the model.
3. The controller updates the model and repaints / revalidates the view.

A Swing GUI can have many controller classes. I created three controller classes for this tic-tac-toe game.  Two of the three controller classes are expressed as lambda expressions because they are simple.

I created 5 different classes. One class makes up the application model, one class defines the view, and three controller classes manage the application.

### Model

The `GameModel` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that creates a logical tic-tac-toe board and keeps track of whose turn it is.

### View

Every Swing application must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and updated on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I use a `JFrame` and create a button `JPanel` and a grid `JPanel`.  The JFrame has a default `BorderLayout`.  I put the button `JPanel` at NORTH and the grid `JPanel` in the CENTER.

The button `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` and the grid `JPanel` uses, you guessed it, a `GridLayout`.  I added an empty border around both `JPanels` to add some whitespace to the GUI.

I used a `Box` `createHorizontalStrut` method to add some whitespace to the button `JPanel`.

### Controller

The reset button and quit button controllers are simple lambda expressions.

I made nine instances of the `MoveListener` class, one for each button in the tic-tac-toe grid.  This makes the `actionPerformed` code rather simple.  The only logic is to check to make sure the square is empty before making the move.

For some reason, checking for spaces didn't work, so I check for the absence of an 'X' or an 'O'.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

I tested this code and it works.  Save it somewhere safe before you make lots of changes and then gripe that it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleTicTacToeGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleTicTacToeGUI());
    }

    private final GameModel model;
    
    private JButton[] gridButtons;
    
    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel turnLabel;
    
    public SimpleTicTacToeGUI() {
        this.model = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createGrid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(16f);
        
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Replay?");
        resetButton.setFont(font);
        resetButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            model.resetModel();
            updateGUI();
            enableButtons();
        });
        panel.add(resetButton);
        
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        turnLabel = new JLabel(model.getTurn() + "'s turn");
        turnLabel.setFont(font);
        panel.add(turnLabel);
        
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit!");
        quitButton.setFont(font);
        quitButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        });
        panel.add(quitButton);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createGrid() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 72f);
        
        gridButtons = new JButton[model.getBoard().length];
        for (int index = 0; index < gridButtons.length; index++) {
            gridButtons[index] = new JButton(" ");
            MoveListener listener = new MoveListener(this, model, index);
            gridButtons[index].addActionListener(listener);
            gridButtons[index].setFont(font);
            gridButtons[index].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(96, 96));
            panel.add(gridButtons[index]);
        }

        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateGUI() {
        char[] board = model.getBoard();
        for (int index = 0; index < gridButtons.length; index++) {
            String s = Character.toString(board[index]);
            gridButtons[index].setText(s);
        }
        turnLabel.setText(model.getTurn() + "'s turn");
    }
    
    public void disableButtons() {
        for (int index = 0; index < gridButtons.length; index++) {
            gridButtons[index].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    
    private void enableButtons() {
        for (int index = 0; index < gridButtons.length; index++) {
            gridButtons[index].setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    
    public JButton getButton(int index) {
        return gridButtons[index];
    }
    
    public class MoveListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final int index;
        
        private final SimpleTicTacToeGUI view;
        
        private final GameModel model;

        public MoveListener(SimpleTicTacToeGUI view, GameModel model,
                int index) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String s = view.getButton(index).getText();
            if (!(s.equals("X") || s.equals("O"))) {
                model.makeMove(index);
                view.updateGUI();
                if (model.isGameOver()) {
                    view.disableButtons();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class GameModel {
        
        private char[] board;
        private char turn;
        
        public GameModel() {
            resetModel();
        }
        
        public void resetModel() {
            this.board = new char[9];
            this.turn = 'X';
        }
        
        public void makeMove(int index) {
            board[index] = turn;
            turn = (turn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
        }
        
        public boolean isGameOver() {
            int[][] indexes = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 },
                    { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 }, { 0, 4, 8 },
                    { 2, 4, 6 } };
            for (int index = 0; index < indexes.length; index++) {
                if (checkRow('X', indexes[index])
                        || checkRow('O', indexes[index])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        private boolean checkRow(char player, int[] indexes) {
            for (int index = 0; index < indexes.length; index++) {
                if (board[indexes[index]] != player) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            return true;
        }

        public char getTurn() {
            return turn;
        }

        public char[] getBoard() {
            return board;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Yo bro, It did not actually work, I just posted all of my codes above, if you pleaes konw how I would be able to do it, Please help me with that.

Comment: @Mustafa: What didn't work?  There's no functionality.  I just created the GUI.  If no button disappears, then I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Yea you're right, but actually when I added your code to mine and checked it the things you had in your code and I didn't, after running it, it actually did not work. I mean I posted the whole code above, you can now see how everything is set up, mybe I added it incorrectly, but I tried and added some of the things you had in your code and I did not, it did not work brother.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc, You don't know how much all the effort you put to help me means to me, I really really really apreciate you in advacne, Thanks a lot Brother.

Comment: Hello Gilbert, I appreciate your work and everything. But as you can see in my own code, how do you think I can add the 2 buttons Replay and the Quit Button in my own code? Because Honestly, your code is really hard to understand because it's written so professionally, and I don't understand much of it, would you please please help me to add the functionality of both buttons in my own code?

Comment: @Mustafa: The reason I wrote the code the way I did is because my version is correct and your version is confusing, verbose, and hard for me to understand.  If you have specific questions, you can ask a new Stack Overflow question and post my code as an example of code you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert, You're right about that. I'm basically creating a new question in regards of How I can play the tik-tak-toe game against computer. I'd be happy if you help me with that as well.